# Deploy python script on google cloud platform

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I'm figuring out how to deploy my script on google cloud platform.
ive already made a directory or folder that contains the `script.py`and all the libraries in `/lib` folder.

what i dont get is setting up my `app.yaml` to run `script.py` (python 2.7) and access `lib` if it needs to.

I also dont know if i need to make `requirments.txt` since im using third party libraries.

here are all my imports inside `script.py`

```
import requests
import re
import mysql.connector
from urlparse import urlparse
from urlparse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Also, what i have in my `lib` are BeautifulSoup,requests and mysql.connector.
i dont know about the others i assume they're python2.7 built in since i cant install them using pip.

im using windows 10 by the way.

app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true



handlers:
- url: /lib/requests
  script: Scrape.app

handlers:
- url: /requests
  script: Scrape.app

handlers:
- url: /mysql/connector
  script: Scrape.app

handlers:
- url: /bs4/
  script: Scrape.app
```

cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: "Scrape"
  url: /
  schedule: every 10 mins
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
    max_doublings: 10
```

im getting errors like

```
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                                                                                                          
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:
/bin/sh: 1: Python: not found
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File  "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tribal-bonito-157700/20170302t182530.399552845921654287/Scrape.py", line 3, in <module>
import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Answer (score 3):

From the **script** row in the [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) table:

> A **script:** directive must be a python import path, for example,
>   **package.module.app** that points to a WSGI application. The last component of a **script:** directive using a **Python module** path is
>   the name of a global variable in the module: that variable must be a
>   WSGI app, and is usually called **app** by convention.
>
> Note: just like for a Python **import** statement, each subdirectory
>   that is a package must contain a file named [`__init__.py`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

I'd recommend spending some time going through the code snippets from [Quickstart for Python App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/quickstart), where you'll see a basic structure of a simple app.

A `requirements.txt` file can be used to specify the list of packages to be installed in the `lib` directory, like this:

`pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib`

But it's not *absolutely necessary*, packages can be explicitly specified directly on the `pip` cmdline as well.

Comment: can i set in `app.yaml` when to run the code? for example every 24hrs app enging is gonna run the code.

Comment: oh boy,,heres another term i stumbled upon`cron.yaml`. any ideas where to add `X-Appengine-Cron: true` or am i doing this wrong?

Comment: Spend some time on the documentation site, you need get your bearings first. Check the left-side navigation bar, you'll find articles on How-to Guides, Concepts, Tutorials, References, etc. For cron start with https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron