# Can anyone correct my app.yaml and cron.yaml? Google cloud platform

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, repository, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I have a python code `scrape.py` and i want to run it on app engine,,it is stored in my repository and the libraries are all in the folder `lib`.

can anyone please correct my app.yaml and cron.yaml.

my imports

```
import requests
import re
import mysql.connector
from urlparse import urlparse
from urlparse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  script: Scrape.app

handlers:
- url: /lib/requests
  script: Scrape.app

handlers:
- url: /requests
  script: Scrape.app

handlers:
- url: /mysql/connector
  script: Scrape.app

handlers:
- url: /bs4/
  script: Scrape.app
```

handlers:
    - url: /lib/mysql/connector
      script: Scrape.app

```
handlers:
- url: /lib/bs4/
  script: Scrape.app
```

cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: "Scrape"
  url: /
  schedule: every 10 mins
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
    max_doublings: 10
```

i notice my cron.yaml works because in my app engines stats,,theres been an activity every 10m but i dont know if this is right to run the code every 10m.

**Errors**

---

```
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                                                                                                          
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:
/bin/sh: 1: Python: not found
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tribal-bonito-157700/20170302t182530.399552845921654287/Scrape.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploy python script on google cloud platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547973/deploy-python-script-on-google-cloud-platform)

Answer (score 0):

Your `cron.yaml` targets `/`, but there's no handler for `/` in `app.yaml`.

You say the stats are showing activity. Are the logs showing errors?

Comment: Yes, the logs ar showing error like python not found. But i notice the graph going up on app engine every 10m

Comment: @Boneyflesh did your install `requests` library inside lib folder?

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes i did,,infact i used pip to install it on `lib` directory and then added it to my git repository.